# How to load reduce output into HBase?

Tags: hbase

Using the WordCount example of MapReduce tutorial, I am changing the code to load the reduce() output into HBase table. Would anyone please suggest the changes in the code of WordCount example. It would be of great help to me. Thanks.

Comment: Please stop rolling back the edits. You're making such a drastic change that your question no longer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following codes to write your reducer, since you use the old API. You need to implement `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableReduce<Text, IntWritable>`:

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
    TableReduce<Text, IntWritable> {

public static final byte[] CF = "cf".getBytes();
public static final byte[] COUNT = "count".getBytes();

@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
        OutputCollector<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> output,
        Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    int i = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
        i += values.next().get();
    }
    Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(key.toString()));
    put.add(CF, COUNT, Bytes.toBytes(i));
    output.collect(null, put);
}
}
```

If you find any error, you can check if you use the classes in package `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.*`.

Remeber adding the following line to set up the JobConf:

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReduceJob("wordcount", Reduce.class, conf);
```

Your codes are typed wrong. It's `initTableReduceJob` instead of `initTableReducerJob`. Here "wordcount" is the HBase table name. You need to create the table before running your application.

Comment: Although you do not need to create HBaseConfiguration by yourself, I suggest you create one to make sure the configuration is correct. `Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create(); JobConf conf = new JobConf(config, WordCountHBase.class);`